# Create Glade XML files from Gtk C++ source & header files

Tags: gtk, glade

I have received Gtk C++ source & header files. Is there a way to reverse engineer these files to Glade XML files?

Comment: 1.- Glade is deprecated in someway, you should use GtkBuilder instead. 2.- No.

Comment: @Joel *lib*glade is deprecated; glade the file format and glade the software program are still used

Comment: @andlabs, sure we can avoid external libraries when the core of gtk has a support it one, right?

Comment: @Joel no, what I'm saying is calling .ui files "glade files" is still correct because Glade is still the software used to build them, it's just that the stuff to use them is now part of GTK+ itself

Comment: And yes, you can't automatically convert C code to a Glade XML file, because C code can do whatever it wants and be formatted in a number of ways that makes static analysis effectively impossible. You'll have to recreate the GUI from scratch; sorry.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to reverse assemble a C++ file into a Glade file. Consider three reasons this is so:

- C++ is much more versatile than Glade. It has so much flexibility that to ask a piece of software to cram it into an inflexible format like Glade would be nearly impossible. The software to do this would have to be as big as Glade itself.
- There's a lot of pain, no gain. What do you gain by reverse assembling it? C++ is already the more flexible platform; Glade is only made available for people who don't want to do all their layout dynamically (in code). If you already have code in C++, you're better off than if you were just given Glade files to work with.
- C++ wouldn't be the first choice of language to do this with. If there was such a thing, it would be released natively for C first. Since there is no such tool for C, I think we can be sure there is no such tool for C++, a language for which GTK+ must use a binding.

My advice: stick with your C++ files. You're better off with them.